# How update OpenStack in Pike version installed by Kolla-Ansible

Tags: installation, openstack

How I can update OpenStack from Pike version to last.
It was installed my OpenStack by Kolla-Ansible.

https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/pike/

Answer (score 1):

It's better to update your cluster to **one version** upper than yours. for instance, your cluster version is `PIKE` and you should update it to `QUEENS` version.

For doing update without any risks, I recommend you to [read this documentations](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/operating-kolla.html) and do it step by step.

Of course, you should do it in your lab environment first!

Hope you succeed!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@MilaDroid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70484852/139985), I think that you should read and follow the advice in [OpenStack Upgrades](https://docs.openstack.org/operations-guide/ops-upgrades.html).  Especially if your Openstack installation us running something important.

Note that latest OpenStack release is Xena, so you are currently 8 releases behind.  Also, note that if you are using Ubuntu, you have 2 operating system upgrades to make in this process; Xenial -> Bionic and Bionic -> Focal.

All in all, it is probably simpler to rebuild your cluster from scratch.